# What are common terms for sections of a web application behind and not-behind login?

Tags: web-app, terminology, organization

I'm looking for some concise recognizable terms to help code organization for pages or content of a web application that are either behind a login or not behind a login.

Answer (score 2):

- authenticated vs. guest
- logged in vs. not logged in
- hot state vs. cold state
- private vs. public

Comment: Awesome, I came up with *private vs. public* myself before I posted my question but didn't want to bias the results. I also like *authenticated vs. guest*.